# Wrong row indexes in datagridview upon loading

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, master-detail

**My problem:**

I'm trying to make master detail form.
So as I load my datasources and set everything up, I noticed that my beginning row in bindingnavigator is 3, and whenever i navigate previous it will switch me back to 1st and once i get there i can't navigate with next past initial row (3)

I discovered that my 3rd row and 1st row have same index = 0 and that is causing the problem. I have no clue how could this bug happen

[These are my rows and suspected index values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDBBr.jpg)

While debugging upon setting the datasource i tried to set CurrentCell.Value to 3 and this changed first row

[CurrentCell is first row but navigating is starting from third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvnDq.jpg)

And finally the navigating problem if I start from third row navigate to fourth and than navigate back again this loop will happen 1st-3rd row and i can't move past 3rd

Here's the sample of my code till the form loads:

```
        private async void Studijski_program_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await LoadDataSources();
        UpdateDisplay(false);

        //Filter();
    }

    private async Task LoadDataSources()
    {
        //visual stuff
        sTUDIJSKIPROGRAMBindingNavigator.Visible = false;
        nastavniPlanProgramsDataGridView.Visible = false;
        panel1.Visible = false;

        //detail datasource (this is left datagridview
        nastavniPlanProgramsBindingSource.DataSource = await master.NastavniPlanPrograms.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();


        ///some code for comboboxes in datagridview not to cause error
        List<Predmet> predmeti = await master.Predmets.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        predmeti.Insert(0, new Predmet
        {
            idPredmet = 0,
            nazivPredmet = "--Odaberi Predmet--"
        });
        predmetBindingSource.DataSource = predmeti;

        List<VRSTAIZVODJENJAPREDMETA> vrsta = await master.VRSTAIZVODJENJAPREDMETAs.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        vrsta.Insert(0, new VRSTAIZVODJENJAPREDMETA
        {
            idVrIzvodPred = 0,
            Vrsta = "--Odaberite Vrstu--"
        });
        vRSTAIZVODJENJAPREDMETABindingSource.DataSource = vrsta;
        ///

        //master datasource (left datagridview) This one is causing problem
        await master.STUDIJSKIPROGRAMs.OrderBy(d => d.idStudProg).LoadAsync();
        sTUDIJSKIPROGRAMBindingSource.DataSource = master.STUDIJSKIPROGRAMs.Local.ToBindingList();



        //visual stuff
        sTUDIJSKIPROGRAMBindingNavigator.Visible = true;
        nastavniPlanProgramsDataGridView.Visible = true;
        panel1.Visible = true; 


    }
```

Comment: As I need more than 10 rep to post >2 links here's the third visually displaying loop   http://i.stack.imgur.com/cYtKn.jpg

Comment: What happens if you bind to the result of the `LoadAsync` instead of `Local`?